# Python match text successfully even when there are 1, 2 and 3 backslash at front of the same regex pattern

Tags: python, regex

I have this observation when I run it in the interpreter.

```
>>> re.match('\\\x07bc', '\abc')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x000000000340D308>

>>> re.match('\\x07bc', '\abc')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x000000000340D370>

>>> re.match('\x07bc', '\abc')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x000000000340D308>
```

Why would Python match the same text with single, double and triple backslash at the front?

Comment: third case: obvious. for the other cases, it seems that regex engine is able to understand `\x` on its own (did not find it in the documentation though, so I cannot answer formally). All 3 cases work for me BTW

Comment: \\ is equal to escaping \ but hex needs to be \x, with this logic I have an mind blow :_D, I think the first one only be the correct

Comment: @ZiTAL the first one should match `"\\abc"` (5c 07 62 63). Only third one should be correct.

Comment: @UrielEli I think  "\\" = "\" and "\x07" = "a", because how to differentiate hexadecimal "x07" from "x07" string?

Comment: Thats what I wrote, and `\x07` is `\a`, `a` is `\x61`. I added hex values.

Comment: Please let me know if the question I linked gives you enough information to understand your observations in this question.

Comment: Beside the details in the original question, note that the `re.match` finds matches only at the start of string, and the matches are found right there. Also, see http://ideone.com/ZzyRyf.

Comment: This thread that @PM 2Ring linked [How python and the regex module handle backslashes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35797446/how-python-and-the-regex-module-handle-backslashes) has the correct answer and it is explained well why it happened.