# Python regular expression escaping

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to use `(?<!\\)#` to match `#`s without a `\` in the front (the task is to escape the unescaped `#`s in a string). This regex works on several online regex validators. However it doesn't work with the python `re` module. I also tried escaping the symbols in the regex, but it either produces errors or does not produce the expected output.

```py
re.sub("(?<!\\)#","\#",'asd\#fh## #')
```

How can I modify this regex so it can produce the output `asd\\#fh\\#\\# \\#`(The output has `\`s escaped so there are double `\\`)?

Comment: Use it like this: `re.sub(r"(?<!\\)#", r"\\#", r'asd\#fh## #')`

Comment: @anubhava thanks! didn't know about raw strings. Can you post it as an answer so that I can accept it ?

Comment: See [Confused about backslashes in regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33582162/confused-about-backslashes-in-regular-expressions). Also, [How python and the regex module handle backslashes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35797937/3832970). Replacing with backslashes: [Escape special characters in a Python string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12012114/3832970).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have few issues in your code:

1. `'asd\#fh## #'` is same as `'asd#fh## #'` in normal string (unless you use raw string mode)
2. Likewise `"\#"` in replacement is same as just `#`
3. Similarly `"(?<!\\)#"` will generate regex syntax error as it will become `(?<!\)#` without matching `)` for negative lookahead

You need to use [raw string mode](https://www.pythontutorial.net/python-basics/python-raw-strings/) or use double escaping to get it right:

```py
repl = re.sub(r"(?<!\\)#", r"\#", r'asd\#fh## #')
# repl = 'asd\\#fh\\#\\# \\#'
```